# how do i remove an object from an ArrayList by passing a String parameter rather than passing the object itself?

Tags: java

I want to be able to remove the `ParkingSlot` object passing string instead of the object reference?

Do I need to convert the `ParkingSlot` object to `String` type and match the `String` inside the `removeSlot` method?

```
public class CarPark {
    
    private ArrayList<ParkingSlot> slots = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public void addParkingSpot(ParkingSlot slot) {
        if(!slots.contains(slot)) {
            slots.add(slot);
        }
        
    }
    public void removeSlot(ParkingSlot slot) {
        slots.remove(slot);    //i want to pass a string here instead of an Object??
    }
    
    
    public ArrayList<ParkingSlot> getSLots() {
        return slots; 
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("slot- %s", slots);
    }

package assignment1;

public class ParkingSlot {
    
    private String spotID;
    
    
    
    public ParkingSlot(String spotID) {
        
        this.spotID = spotID;
        
    }
    
     public String getParkingSlot(){
            return spotID;
        }
    
    public String toString() {
        return spotID ;
    }
    
    
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        
        ParkingSlot downcast = (ParkingSlot) obj;
        return this.getParkingSlot().equals(downcast.getParkingSlot());
    }
}
```

Comment: `slots.removeIf(mySlot -> mySlot.getParkingSlot().equals(spotIDString))`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, this works, but I am not sure whats happening?? im just starting to learn and I am not familiar with the "-->" yet. and how come i get access to the getparkingSlot() method inside the CarkPark class? lol . sorry i am a nood lol.